# Hello I'm new to Java Programming and I'm trying to develop a pet program that reads and counts the types of pet a user inputs

Tags: java, loops

I have tried using the Scanner & Stringtokenizer classes to count the number of times a specific pet is inputed but end up getting the no output. I cannot seem to figure out what method I need to count the number of pets(dogs, cat, etc..) so I can get the right output for the number of dogs, cats, etc.

```
String pet,temp, output, dog = "dog", cat ="cat", other ="other";
    double payment, totalPayment = 0, dogCount = 0, catCount = 0, otherCount = 0, totalDogNum = 0;
    int more = 0;



    while(more == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
    pet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "Enter the pet type ", "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter the payment for the appointment ", "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    payment = Double.parseDouble(temp);

    more = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to add another pet?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );

    if (pet == dog )
    {
        dogCount = dogCount + 1;
    }
    else if (pet == cat)
    {
        catCount += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        otherCount += 1;
    }

    totalPayment += payment;
    }



    output =  "Number of Dogs: "+ dogCount
            + "\n" + "Number of Cats: " + catCount
            + "\n" + "Number of Other Pets: " + otherCount
```

Comment: You are not printing the output. Add `System.out.println(output);` at the end of your code

Comment: Also. `pet == dog` is wrong since they are strings you should use `pet.equals(dog)` same for the else if.

Comment: Thanks pet.equals(dog) fixed my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the pet using the equals method.
`if (pet.equals(dog) )`

And print the output string to the console:
`System.out.println(output);`

or to a JOptionPane
`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);`

Comment: Thanks that works for me.